# Is there a way to target my bow without using the mouse?

Tags: dungeonmans

I'm playing a Rangermans, which means I'm using my bow often. I like using the numeric keypad to run around, and if I want to melee, I can just walk into an enemy to attack them. However, whenever I want to use the bow, I have to move my hand over to the mouse and target an enemy.

Is there any way to target ranged attacks using the keyboard instead of using the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If turns out that hitting "f" brings up the targeting window, and from there you can use the arrow keys to select your target. It seems to be semi-intelligent about selecting a nearby enemy.

This is also useful if you want to target an enemy who is underneath a UI element, such as your health/stamina bar, since you can't click on them with the mouse in that case. But if you press "f", the UI overlay disappears and you can now target them.

Additionally, it allows you to fire a bow at an adjacent enemy, which doesn't seem to be possible using just the mouse.